# Phoenix deployment on Heroku failed to bind $PORT

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have big issues with deploying my application on heroku server. I've done it with help of tutorial from phoenix webpage. But it doesn't work. Below you can see the logs and configuration i used.

heroku logs

```
2016-02-07T04:28:55.623435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-02-07T04:28:55.623435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-02-07T04:28:56.344649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-02-07T04:28:56.348324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-02-07T09:54:29.124036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-02-07T09:54:34.703208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `m
ix run --no-halt`
2016-02-07T09:55:35.386922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-02-07T09:55:35.386922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-02-07T09:55:36.330258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-02-07T09:55:36.323082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-02-07T12:14:35.182306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=kpsz.herokuapp.com request_id=7de0ee97-14cf-46f9-
a9a3-cbffa09ac379 fwd="83.7.11.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-02-07T12:14:35.850018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kpsz.herokuapp.com request_id=4e9b1979
-deb6-497b-80b2-655615f43d01 fwd="83.7.11.212" dyno= connect= service= status=50
3 bytes=
```

Configuration prod.exs

```
config :kpsz, Kpsz.Endpoint,
  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT")],
  url: [host: "example.com", port: 80],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")

config :kpsz, Kpsz.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"),
  pool_size: 20
```

Comment: This is happening for me too. I'm wondering if it's a bug with the buildpack.

Comment: Recreating heroku app fixed it for me

Comment: Were you changing MIX_ENV on Heroku when this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heroku destroy project name

heroku create

and for some weird reason it works now...

Thanks very much for help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that's the problem but you could try to replace

`http: [port: System.get_env("PORT")]`

with

`http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}]`

At least that's what I'm using in my apps. You can also read the docs for more information http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
Adding a Procfile with a single line `web: mix phoenix.server` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and, for me, the fix was as follow (copied from the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229960/234025)).

The fix is twofold:

1. to use the phoenix buildpack config and export the PORT as well, like so: config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL PORT)
2. Avoid changing the MIX_ENV without recompiling the app, as that behavior is unsupported, as explained here.

Answer (score 0):

As **Recreation** solves the problem, I suspect the problem is with **loading** environment variables.

Once I had a similar problem in my local. My observations

1. mix phoenix.server (you might see the message compiled so and so files)
2. Stopped the server
3. Export/Change the env variable in zshrc/bashrc file and source it
4. Start the server (you might not see that compilation message, as there are no changes in your codebase and so your new/edited env variables won't get reflected)
5. If you just add a space in that file will make it compile and take that env variable.

**Reason for your problem might be:** Setting env variables after the server is running/deployed, as env variables are converted to value during the compilation time itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when deploying the phoenix umbrella project with docker.
I've taken these steps:
Heroku https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/heroku.html#deploying-to-heroku-using-the-container-stack
Dockerfile https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#containers
I've also looked at other links, but these two was the best.

---

The only problem with that Dockerfile is that it needs $PORT (and $SECRET_KEY_BASE) on the build step which is not present. So we have to "stub" it somehow in prod.exs. BUT we have to provide real $PORT on a run step (runtime configuration). So you have to be sure that you renamed `config/prod.secret.exs` to `config/releases.exs` (the 1 step at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/releases.html#runtime-configuration) or just create `config/releases.exs` which would rewrite $PORT (and maybe some other application environment variables - for example, $SECRET_KEY_BASE).

UPD: as @Daniel mentions - `releases` is an Elixir 1.9 feature.

Comment: You should mention that `releases` is a new feature, when this question was asked there was only a hacky workaround to get environment variables at runtime.